# send and receive multiple pieces of data with ajax in php files

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am trying to use Ajax in my PHP files to accept input from a form and return data which I then use Ajax to receive and display in HTML. The data I am receiving is correct but is not displaying correctly, also, sometimes I am getting a random success string come through which also displays. Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function ajax_post(){
    $.post("server.php", { 
        username: $("#userName").val(),
        password: $("#userPass").val() 
    }, 
    function(username,pass) {
    $("#username").html(username);
    $("#pass").html(pass);
    });
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Ajax Post to PHP and Get Return Data</h2>
Username: <input id="userName" name="userName" type="text">  <br><br>
Password: <input id="userPass" name="userPass" type="password">  <br><br>
<input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Check" onclick="ajax_post()"> <br><br>
<p id="username" style="color:red"></p><br><br>
    <p id="pass" style="color:red"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

server.php:

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST['username'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        echo 'You are now registered,' . $username;
        echo 'Password: ' . $pass;
}
?>
```

here is a screenshot of the result I get once I run the index.php file and fill in the forms, what I am trying to do is display the returned username data in the username paragraph and the password in the password paragraph, again I have no idea where that 'success' is coming from. [image: result in browser]

Comment: If you are writing new code you may as well try using the latest jQuery, not something `jquery/1.11.3` this old

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this is by putting your echoed data into an JSON formatted array like this:

```
    echo json_encode([
        'msg' => 'You are now registered,' . $username,
        'username' => $username,
        'pass' => $pass
    ]);
```

Your post request should look like this:

```
    $.post("server.php", {
      username: $("#userName").val(),
      password: $("#userPass").val()
    }, function(data) {
      var returnedData = JSON.parse(data)
      $("#username").html(returnedData.username);
      $("#pass").html(returnedData.pass);
    });
```

**NOTE:** Do not forget to parse the JSON array into something that javascript can read using `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: No problem @PaPaB1nG0 , I do this stuff very often and enjoyed your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that returning json from PHP, and use it in js.
So in the PHP file you will have:

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    // Here you return json
    echo json_encode([
        'msg' => 'You are now registered,' . $username,
        'username' => $username,
        'pass' => $pass
    ]);
}
?>
```

While in the html file you will have:

```
$.post("server.php", { 
    username: $("#userName").val(),
    password: $("#userPass").val() 
}, function(data) {
    $("#username_1").html(data.username);
    $("#pass_1").html(data.pass);
});
```

**NOTE**
You do not need to return username and password from the server since they are just the input you inserted. I write the code as an example for using json.

**UPDATED**
You need to change also your HTML with this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#myBtn').click(function() {
            $.post("server.php", {
                username: $("#userName").val(),
                password: $("#userPass").val()
            }, function(data) {
                $("#username_1").html(data.username);
                $("#pass_1").html(data.pass);
            });
        }):
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Ajax Post to PHP and Get Return Data</h2>
        Username: <input id="userName" name="userName" type="text">  <br><br>
        Password: <input id="userPass" name="userPass" type="password">  <br><br>
        <input name="myBtn" type="button" value="Check" id="myBtn"> <br><br>
        <p id="username_1" style="color:red"></p><br><br>
        <p id="pass_1" style="color:red"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your for your answer, when i replace the parts of my code with yours it does not seem to display anything

Comment: try `console.log(data)` inside the post function to see what you get from server.php

Comment: the problem is not in the call

Comment: i wouldnt say so as it was working with normal ajax

Comment: it was not working with ajax. It was working as normal html post

Comment: Giacomo, your update for HTML works, but everything is outputting as JSON and still not in the correct paragraphs

Comment: I edited the html part, it should work right now. If it does not work, try with `console.log(data)` in post function.

Comment: the console says that there is an error on line 13 at the ``);``

Comment: when I ``console.log`` the data it displays the correct JSON data but does not access specific parts, like when I say ``console.log(data.username);`` it will return undefined

Comment: write what you get with console.log

Comment: So I get  ``{"username":"user","pass":"pass"}`` when i ``console.log(data)``. When i say ``$("#username").html(data.username);
                $("#pass").html(data.pass);`` nothing happens

Comment: well, i did not see that you have 2 element with id "username" and 2 elements with id "pass". The ids must be unique in the page

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to here. If you are referring to the names of the JSON  response I have changed them to ``{"user":"user","p":"pass"}`` to see if that makes any difference and it does not

Comment: thanks for your help, the answer above from Ahm23 worked for me